# C# selectionsort with recursion and arraylists not working due to position holder i

Tags: recursion, arraylist, selection-sort

```
static void DoSelectionSortRecursive(ArrayList Integers)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int min = i;
        for (int index = i + 1; index < Integers.Count; index++)
        {
            if ((int)Integers[index] > (int)Integers[min])
            {
                min = index;
            }
        }
        Swap(i, min, Integers);

        if (i + 1 < Integers.Count)
        {
            DoSelectionSortRecursive(Integers, i + 1, Integers.Count);
        }
    }
```

**The value of i was bringing up syntax errors, so i declared it before hand but that caused the recursive method call to become a syntax error. Im using Arraylists so the coding got a little complicated, but all my code is based on the use of arraylists in my other methods, so if anyone can shed some light on what im doing wrong that would be great. Im trying to essentially create a recursive selection sort method**

Comment: `DoSelectionSortRecursive` takes 1 argument, a list of integers; you are passing it 3.

Comment: ohh, cant believe i missed that. Thanks so much, just made the correction. So i know the above method has a for loop, as well as a recursive call. So is my function considered recursive, or must i put the for loop in another method and then call it into the recursive sort method to get rid of the iteration where it traverses through the list

Comment: If it calls itself, its recursive.